# WSO2 MB 3.0.0 Subscriptions and Message Counter Metrics

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker

I've deployed a WSO2 MB cluster configuration (2 nodes) and I would like to know if there is some way to retreive by metrics the following informations for user/tenant:

- number of subscritions per topic
- number of messages sent by publishers
- number of messages delivered to subscribers
- dimension of the messages arrived
- a monitor of the connected users to the topic

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by the 'dimension of the messages arrived'? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Number of subscriptions per topic - You can find this information in Management console > Subscriptions > Topic Subscription List UI. Please keep in mind there is no filtering criteria applied at the moment.

Number of messages sent by publishers - You can view the message count sent by the publisher if  no one is subscribing. This means in Message Broker, it only shows the message count in the queue at a given point.

Number of messages delivered to subscribers - Same as above. But, for durable topic subscriptions, individually delivered counts are shown.

Dimension of the messages arrived - Please clarify what you mean by "dimension"

a monitor of the connected users to the topic - For this, subscription UI can be used. It is possible to view message content and header of messages individually.

Regards,
Pubudu.